# Touchscreen not detected after install latest Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchscreen

I bought a new ultrabook (EXO brand). It cames with win8, and everything workd fine. After remove win8 and install ubuntu 14.04 the touchscreen and touchpad were not recognized by the SO: ls usb, lspci, xinput --list. 
I solved the touchpad issue by modifiyng the grub.
However I am unable to make the touchscreen to be detected and of couse to work.
Any ideas?
Thans

Comment: Can you tell us what you did to fix the touch pad?

Comment: I just follow this instructions: 
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Append "i8042.nopnp " to "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT".

*where i8042.nopnp=1 solves the touchpad probem.

It will look like this :

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp"

Save and exit.

sudo update-grub

Comment: @LucasMongiat you should update your question about the touchpad to reflect this. Your question is unsolved. Also, I have a very similar problem, did you ever get the touchscreen to work?